# "Team Foundation services are not available from" Visual Studio Online

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops

I am using tfs preview, which is provided by Microsoft online. I am able to get the project name but when I am trying to get work items. I am getting below error.

> TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server
>   https://servername.tfspreview.com/.
>
> Technical information (for administrator):
>
> Page not found.

I am using below code to get work items.

```
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection("https://servername.tfspreview.com/");
var store = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(ICommonStructureService));
```

Comment: Specify the collection name.  eg, `https://servername.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Team Foundation Service` is no longer in preview mode. It's a full freemium service. Update your URL to:

```
https://servername.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
```

Comment: @alok_dida I guess the problem is authentication. look at this blog post [How to connect to TF Service without a prompt for LiveID credentials](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-connect-to-tf-service-without-a-prompt-for-liveid-credentials.aspx)